# How to connect 3 ip camera through a router to a pc?

Tags: networking, router, ip-camera

I want to connect 3 IP cameras to a pc and capture their images in fair fps and process their image on pc by a program. I don’t need to capture the images from all of 3 cameras at the same time, just each time one of cameras as source is enough so I don’t use too much bandwidth. The supplier of camera suggests a router (as it shown in the below pictures and I prefer to use TP-LINK TL-R402M) and the camera has a built in server (for config and administration). The supported protocols on this cam are Onvif (port is 889) RTSP (port is 554)/ FTP/PPPoE/DHCP/DDNS/NTP/UPnP. Moreover, all type of IP cams support H.264/MJPEG on a stream through the IP. 
In the internet most of materials are about connecting various devices by routers and switchers but for wired IP cams there are not good sources of information. Can you please guide me what type of router this company means and is the mentioned router useful or I have to choose something else? Is that possible to use just a switcher?

i.imgur.com/mJCKHKk.jpg

i.imgur.com/oyrLYX2.jpg

i.imgur.com/K5H5XNm.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The images you posted are not visible.  But in general

If the IP cameras are on the same network as the computer then you should not require a router.  Often it is best practice to setup your devices in a simple test network and get it working before moving on to a more complex config.

If you are wishing to view the cameras from outside your local network, then you may require a router that does port forwarding.  Most routers do, in the advanced configs.  Your ISP may already be providing you with the router, and may or may not give you config privileges.  The possibility exists that you may be prohibited, no matter what you do.  Time to change ISP.

IF the cameras are of the type that contact the manufacturers servers to send photos out to you, then generally if you have web access, then these cams will work through any router/firewall.

Unfortunately, without the photos or more details, it is difficult to provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: please put in front of above links one http:// and they will work. Moreover, here is the link of cam supplier [link] http://www.aliexpress.com/item/2014-Newest-High-Quality-720p-HD-Mini-IP-Camera-Megapixel-1280x720-H-264-ONVIF-Mini-network/2032498178.html you can find all the details about cam and network in same page. I need to make a local network and I don't need to see the cams from out side of network. Just a pc choose the cams ip and capture their image and this happens repeatedly.Any more idea. Thanks

Comment: Looks like a nifty little camera...  It is just a standard IP camera from what I see.  Just hook up to your switch and hit port 80 with a browser.  They will provide the URL in their docs.  If you are looking for software that will poll the cameras and display the images in succession, you can write some simple javascript, if I recall, or you can purchase software for your PC that will poll the cameras.  I use zoneminder, and it works great, but it is pretty complex and requires Linux.

Comment: thanks for reply. I think you didn't get the question. I said "can I use the mentioned router for this work? "  (I didn't buy that yet) or if I should use switch which model? (for me to be affordable is important). The cam is made in China and it doesn't have enough information". Moreover I can't use any third-party soft because it is scientific measurement and I have to write what I need. So the question is, which hardware should I buy router or switch and which model you suggest? Thanks

Comment: English can be a tricky language, it is good that you are trying.  I will say it more clearly. "Just hook up to your switch and hit port 80 with a browser" is your answer.  Or translated.... "Any network switch or hub, by any manufacturer will work."